# iOS6 Pass Row Number from Cell to next View Controller

Tags: ios6, sqlite, uitableview

I have a basic table view cell that is all SQLite3 database generated.

When I click on the Disclosure Indicator in a cell to move to a View Controller so I can edit the contents of the previous cell, how can I just pass the row# or the id# over?

Is there a cute way of doing this in iOS6?

EH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView delegate for your purpose

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      /* your other stuff */
      NSLog ( @\"You selected row: %d\", indexPath.row ); // Gives you row#
}
```

To pass row# to another DetailViewController,
Add following line in DetailViewController.h file

```
@property (readwrite) int selectedRow;
```

And synthsis it in DetailViewController.m file

```
@synthesize selectedRow;
```

Now you can use selectedRow by creating object of DetailViewController like,

```
[detailViewController setSelectedRow:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, that returns the row number perfectly. But what is strange is that it in the logs after the View Controller which is called from the Disclosure Indicator has been called. Is there an easy way to pass this number to the editing View Controller or do I just Seque it?

Comment: Means you want to pass row# to another ViewController?